# SaveChanges hangs the program with Entity Framework 6

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6

With Entity Framework 6, calling `SaveChanges` hangs the program completely. No errors or anything is reported. SQL LocalDB is the database.

```
Dim o As New employee
With o 
   'set some scalar properties here...
   .name="Test"
   ...

   'add set some navigation properties here...
   .parent_company=SelectedCompany
   ...
End With

_context.SaveChanges()
```

What can cause such behavior? I don't understand how this simple object creation could cause deadlock in the database.

Comment: One thing that has bitten me in the past is an error with the connection string and an extremely long timeout.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with EF but are you doing the saving asynchronously? It might help with the hanging of the application.

Comment: I am not using/cannot use async. I have .NET Framework 4.0 and EF6.